# Connection refused from an allowed IP/tag in Google Cloud, firewall is allowed, port is UP and serving

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, cloud, firewall, google-cloud-networking

I'm facing issue with connection to a set of  `Google Cloud` machine from different `VPC`.
The connection is via `nat box/public IP` address from the source( say `Project A`) to destination( say `Project B`) .
There is another set of instances in another project ( say `C`) .
There is a common firewall rule ( `Target Tag`) in place to allow connection from the public IP addresses of both Project.
The connection from `Project C` is working however the connection from `Project A` is not.
I see there are other successful communication among project A and B on other ports and set of instances .
Also, the port and service is UP and running ( we are able to get response on project C's machines )
I tried to capture tcpdump from source and destination.
I dont see any packet at the destination and source has just the `SYN` packet.

```
00:33:27.484091 IP projb-instance-01.c.project-B-123.internal.59300 > 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [S], seq 2180601143, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 2746803643 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

[user@projb-instance-01 ~]$ telnet destination-ip.domain.com 8080
Trying 1.2.3.4...
telnet: connect to address 1.2.3.4: Connection refused



tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
01:22:00.499643 IP projC-instance-01.c.project-c.internal.42259 > 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com.tproxy: Flags [S], seq 1844998068, win 28400, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 4099848389 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
01:22:00.501860 IP 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com.tproxy > projC-instance-01.c.project-c.internal.42259: Flags [S.], seq 2589898876, ack 1844998069, win 28160, options [mss 1420,sackOK,TS val 28180717 ecr 4099848389,nop,wscale 7], length 0
01:22:00.501904 IP projC-instance-01.c.project-c.internal.42259 > 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com.tproxy: Flags [.], ack 1, win 222, options [nop,nop,TS val 4099848391 ecr 28180717], length 0
01:22:04.889432 IP projC-instance-01.c.project-c.internal.42259 > 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com.tproxy: Flags [P.], seq 1:6, ack 1, win 222, options [nop,nop,TS val 4099852779 ecr 28180717], length 5
01:22:04.890293 IP 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com.tproxy > projC-instance-01.c.project-c.internal.42259: Flags [.], ack 6, win 220, options [nop,nop,TS val 28185106 ecr 4099852779], length 0
01:22:04.890390 IP 4.3.2.1.bc.googleusercontent.com.tproxy > projC-instance-01.c.project-c.internal.42259: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 6, win 220, options [nop,nop,TS val 28185107 ecr 4099852779], length 0
```

Steps used for Debuggin:

1. Verify the port is listening on 0 instead of localhost on one of the host behind the service in `Project B`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2578/airflow-backend
```

2. Port and service are reachable from different project's host
   `telnet and curl from a host in project C`
3. Connectivity to Project B from Project A for a different host and port is working

Please suggest me what else can be done to figure out why the connection is getting refused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connection refused usually means that a process is not listening on the port. Make sure your app's listener is not set to **localhost** instead of **0.0.0.0**.

Comment: Thanks John for responding. Yeah, I had verified the process is running and listener is not set to localhost . Also, as I mentioned the service is responding fine to another set of IP address in another project which I think verifies that the service and port are UP and running.

Comment: When debugging, show the steps you performed and the results. Otherwise we have to guess what you did and the results. The fact you state something without the data behind it is the source of a lot of difficult problems. You have overlooked something very simple. Start over and double check everything.

Comment: You mentioned you tried to capture packets with tcpdump from the source and destination and you didn’t see any packets at the destination, but you saw SYN packets at the source. This may imply that there’s a routing issue, where packets are able to get from point A to point B, but can’t return. Could you please try running the traceroute command between both machines? This way we can try to observe at which point the packets are being lost.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc?hl=en)? Since you’re trying to connect VMs across multiple projects, this approach should be the most secure and straightforward to configure and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
Shared VPC is not an option for us, as these projects refer to different environment too so we do not want to share the VPCs

Answer (score 0):

We found that there was an issue with the packet being filtered in the iptables at the nat box, we removed that and it worked